# Dapp in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, truffle

I have do this before the problem

```
truffle unbox webpack
truffle compile
truffle migrate
```

However,when I use "sudo npm run dev",some error occured.Can some tell me how to fix it?Thank you!

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../build/contracts/MetaCoin.json' in '/home/segogt/node1/demo/app/src'
 @ ./src/index.js 2:0-67 15:30-46 17:8-24
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 ./src/index.js
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```